# Unable to update value after adding member to pscustomobject array collection from converted json

Tags: powershell

v5.1

Given the following json -> obj from convertfrom-json

```
$json = @"
{
    "key1":"value1",
    "key2":"value2",
    "key3":[
       "value3a","value3b","value3c"
    ],
    "key4":[
       {
          "id":"id1",
          "name":"name1"
       },
       {
          "id":"id2",
          "name":"name2"
       }
    ]
}
"@
$obj = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $json
```

I add a new member to the key4 array where the collection is id = "id1" without any problem like

```
$rootKey = "key4"
$subKeyValue = "id1"

$newKey = "foo"
$newValue = "bar"

# declare the target collection to modify
$targetCollection=($obj.$rootKey.where{$_.id -eq $subKeyValue})

# if the property/member does not exist create it in the target collection
if (!($targetCollection.$($newKey))) {
   $targetCollection | Add-Member @{$newKey = $newValue}
}
```

The problem arises when I attempt to update this same key in the same collection with a new value, obviously doing it wrong but this is what I expected would work

```
$newValue = 'bar2'

$targetCollection.$newKey = $newValue # = ERROR: The property 'foo' cannot be found on this object   

$targetCollection.foo = $newValue # = ERROR: The property 'foo' cannot be found on this object  

$targetCollection | get-Member
```

Get-Member clearly shows the 'foo' NoteProperty but there seems to be something wrong with my targeting or method I am using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what you have is a collection of objects

```
$targetCollection[0].Foo = "bar"
```

This would work

Also

```
$targetCollection= $obj.$rootKey | Where-Object{$_.id -eq $subKeyValue} | select -first 1
```

Would solve the issue also.

Lets look at the types

In your example `$targetCollection` is type `System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject]`

In my solution `$targetCollection` is type `System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject`

Comment: Thank you! i can't believe i never tried where-object. This is deceptive! The system.array where method seemed terse, deterministic, and suitable since it landed me exactly in the array I wanted, and never thought it would return a different object than where-object, but now I'll be a lot more cautious with checking my types. Thanks again, this works perfectly for my use case.